# Multi store records inside one textarea - ExtJs 4

Tags: javascript, json, cakephp, extjs4

I have been testing extjs4 along with cakephp
and am now stuck on putting mutil store records in one single textarea

I have the fallowing in my .js view file

```
    {
         xtype: 'textarea',
         name : 'notes',
                     //notes will hold foreign_key number
         allowBlank: true,
         fieldLabel: 'Notes',
         editable: false,
         anchor: '100%'
    }
```

This is the .js model file. File I want to call and filter

```
Ext.define('Mc.model.Notes', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
,fields: [
    {name: 'id', type: 'int'}
    ,{name: 'foreign_key', type: 'int'}
    ,{name: 'user_id', type: 'int'}
    ,{name: 'user_name', type: 'string'}
,{name: 'notes', type: 'string'}
,{name: 'all', convert: function(v, record) {
    var note = '- '+record.get('notes');
        var username = ' ('+record.get('user_name')+')\r\n';
        return note , username;
    }}
]});
```

the idea is that all records containing the same foreign_key will be shown inside the textarea. field 'all' to be exact.

Any suggestions please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please don't double post, you asked exactly the same question in the sencha forums, and you got a solid answer there.

--
Bancha - Seamless integrate CakePHP with Sencha Touch and ExtJS
http://banchaproject.org